# How to create a browser bookmark that opens in a new window by default?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, bookmarks

I'm trying to create a bookmarlet that always opens in a new tab without requiring the user to ctrl-click or right-click the bookmarklet.  (Firefox/Chrome)

I tried this:

```
javascript:window.open('https://google.com');
```

and it sort of works: it opens Google in a new tab, but then the current tab's address bar is replaced with the bookmark code, and the current tab's body becomes [object Window].

If I append `window.history.back();` to the bookmarklet, it actually goes back to the page **before** the current one.

Any ideas?

Comment: What browser versions are you testing with? In Chrome 73, I used your exact code and see no changes to the current tab (although I did trigger the pop up blocker occasionally).

Comment: What is the point of this as a bookmarklet? You can open any bookmark in a new tab already using built in features

Comment: @charlietfl The point is to avoid having to do a special operation to open the bookmark in a new tab (i.e. hold the CTRL key while clicking, or right-click and choose "open in new tab").  If there's a native way to achieve this, I'm all ears.

Comment: @Vlad274 I'm testing in Firefox (most recent).

Comment: You're seeing `[object Window]` in the new window because `window.open()` returns that `window` object, and Firefox decides it wants to do something with the return value: show it in the new window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes you get weird bookmarklet behavior when you don't close the document. 
Try this:

```
javascript:var w=window.open();w.location='https://www.google.com';w.document.close();
```

It worked in chrome. I don't have Firefox.

Comment: What exactly is the "close()" statement doing?  Why doesn't it actually close the new tab?

Comment: `document.close()` indicates you're done altering the loaded document. Some browsers require it in a bookmarklet for the document to be displayed correctly, but it may not be necessary for this bookmarklet because you're not changing the document. `window.close()` will attempt to close the window or tab and, depending on browser settings, may pop up a confirmation dialog box.

Comment: The reason for the `[object]` being shown is that `window.open()` returns an object.  `document.close()` does not.  Your bookmarklet should not return a value or it will be displayed in the window.